# Should I include 'Fixed-term' in writing professor's title?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I am an undergraduate student applying to graduate schools. One of my recommenders is my math professor. On the university's webpage and outlook email, his title is 'Fixed Term Assistant Professor'. So I included the 'Fixed term' when I filled out recommender's information on my application portal. Is this appropriate? Does that matter if I drop 'Fixed term' or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is his official title then, yes, you should write it as the university does. Dropping it would be claiming something that isn't true in this case.

The university probably considers "fixed term" to be an important distinction.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!

Comment: Similarly if someone’s title is “Ritt Assistant Professor” at Columbia it would be very misleading to say their title was “Assistant Professor.”  A postdoc and a tenure track position are quite different.

Comment: Though these things are confusing, my colleague Prof. Plavnik is Charlotte Ann Griffin Assistant Professor, but it would still be accurate to say her title is Assistant Professor because it’s a normal assistant professorship with an endowed research fund.  But unless you understand these distinctions you’re best off just literally copying the full title.  Usually the recommender can edit it.

Comment: @Noah Snyder Awesome! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Out of respect for him, I would call him a "Professor". That term is also used generically in many countries, unlike "Full Professor".

I would be embarrassed if he read a form in which I describe him with that title.